# Looping through two sets of files in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, filenames

I have 25 related pairs of files in a folder called Data. These files are named `tcr1_r1.txt` and `tcr1_r2.txt`, `tcr2_r1.txt` and `tcr2_r2.txt`, and so on until I reach `tcr25…` (or how many files pairs I have). My problem is that I need to pair them up and run a command on each pair in a batch file. Example:

```
command  tcr1_r1.txt  tcr2_r2.txt
command  tcr2_r1.txt  tcr2_r2.txt
```

How can I do this?  I'm thinking a loop, but I can't seem to be able to separate and alternate the files on each command. I tried a nested loop but that just runs each "r1" file with all the "r2" files.

```
for filename1 in /Data/*_r1.txt
do
  for filename2 in /Data/*_r2.txt
  do
     echo "$filename1 and $filename2"
  done
done
```

---

I have tried to use [Jeff Schaller’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/527493/23408#527498). 
Here are the exact shell file lines I tried:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for first in /mnt/data/Sequencing_core/Data/Raw_data/062419_TCRB_Vanessa_Danielle/20190624_FS10000703_3_BPC29606-1232/Alignment_1/20190625_132145/Fastq/*R1_001.fastq.gz
do

  echo "$first"
  echo "${first/_R1_001.fastq.gz/_R2_001.fastq.gz}" 

done
```

I must be missing something. 
I’m getting a "Bad substitution" error message.

Comment: I think you made a mistake in writing `command  tcr1_r1.txt  tcr2_r2.txt` - please edit if so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways, depending on whether you want to care about the total number of files.

In the first way, you know the number of files is 25 (specifically named with 1 through 25):

```
for index in {1..25}
do
  command tcr"${index}"_r1.txt tcr"${index}"_r2.txt
done
```

Above, the (bash) shell expands the `{1..25}` to the full set of numbers; we then substitute those numbers into the appropriate place in the paired filenames.

In the second way, you don't know or care how many files there are:

```
for first in tcr*_r1.txt
do 
  command "$first" "${first/_r1.txt/_r2.txt}"
done
```

Above, we loop over all of the "r1" files and substitute the "_r1.txt" part for the paired "_r2.txt".

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html):

```
echo /Data/*_r[12].txt | xargs -n 2 the-command
```