# Unable to run a bash loop in linux by taking two input files as an input?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Newbie to bash scripting, I made script to automate the program to run on 100 different files, can someone please correct the script.
In a directory I had 1 to 100 files with suffix *_R1_sic.fast and *_R2_sic.fast common for all files.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
 
for i in *_R*_sic.fast
do
   SAMPLE=$(echo ${i} | sed "s/_R1_\sic.fast//" | sed "s/_R2_\sic.fast//")
   echo ${SAMPLE}_R1_sic.fast
   echo ${SAMPLE}_R2_sic.fast
time /home/cent/anaconda3/envs/cot_env/bin/cot_cpp cot -k 25 -l 100 -p /home/cent/data/dy_samples/gz/trim/bssp/dat_files/${SAMPLE}_R1_sic.fast /home/cent/data/dy_samples/gz/trim/bssp/dat_files/${SAMPLE}_R2_sic.fast -o /home/cent/data/dy_samples/gz/trim/bssp/dat_files/${SAMPLE}_R_001_trimo25p_shat -t 5 -u 5 -g 150 -m 150G > ${SAMPLE}_R_001_trimo25p_shat_log
done
```

Comment: Very similar: [Looping through two sets of files in bash shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527493/looping-through-two-sets-of-files-in-bash-shell)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well, you're not really saying what the issue is. What happens vs. what you expected to happen etc. Remember we don't have your files or your system to test on.

Comment: when I run the script with 2 files (R1&R2) it not generating output. If I run with 1 file(R1) it generates output. I tested cot_cpp  directly running from the command line, it works. @ilkkachu.

Answer (score 0):

You problably want this:

```bsh
dat_files=/home/cent/data/dy_samples/gz/trim/bssp/dat_files
cot_bin=/home/cent/anaconda3/envs/cot_env/bin

for r1 in *_R1_sic.fast; do
    sample=${r1%_R1_sic.fast}      # trim the _R1... suffix
    r2=${sample}_R2_sic.fast       # add the _R2 suffix
    if [[ -f $r2 ]]; then
        out=${sample}_R_001_trimo25p_shat
        cot_args=(
            -k 25 
            -l 100 
            -p "$dat_files/$r1" "$dat_files/$r2" 
            -o "$dat_files/$out"
            -t 5
            -u 5 
            -g 150 
            -m 150G
        )
        time "$cot_bin/cot_cpp" cot "${cot_args[@]}" > "${out}_log"
    fi
done
```

Comment: When I run the script at the 21 line, it says permission denied boost::filesystem::create_directory: Permission denied: "/8_R_001_trimo25p_shat" @glenn

Comment: Did you declare the `dat_files` variable? Or do you have a typo in the `-o` line?

Comment: I don't have any typo same error.

Comment: Does your script filr have DOS CR+NL line endings?